# Swift - using SceneDelegate with Storyboard : scene unattached

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a new project targeting `iOS 13` and, as expected, it automatically added the `SceneDelegate pattern`. I don't want to enable multiple windows, so I didn't edit anything in the `AppDelegate` and in `SceneDelegate` files. The problem is that `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` is called but the scene is not attached. In fact, if I use this code in the first view controller (in my case, a simple splash screen):

```
let windowScene = UIApplication.shared
                        .connectedScenes
                        .first
if let windowScene = windowScene as? UIWindowScene {
   let popupWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
}
```

The scene status is unattached. What am I missing? I've read that with storyboard there's no need to manually add the scene.

**Edit**: if I try to access windows from `UIApplication`, I also get nil:

```
let w = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
```